# Gulp with production flag breaks an AngularsJS + Laravel app

Tags: angularjs, laravel, gulp

I am new to Gulp, so I've made a mistake somewhere, but I don't know where. My problem is that when I run `gulp --production`, it breaks an application and I am getting an error: `main.js:4 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t`. If I don't use production flag, everything works fine. Here is my gulpfile:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;

/* Copy the neccesary files from node_modules */
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.copy('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts')
       .copy('node_modules/angular/angular.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs')
       .copy('node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs')
       .copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs')
       .copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs')
});

/* CSS stuff */
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass(['app.scss'], 
        'public/css/main.css');
});

/* JavaScript files stuff */
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts([
      'libs/jquery.js',
      'libs/bootstrap.js',
      'libs/angular.js',
      'libs/angular-ui-router.js',

      'components/*/*.module.js',
      'components/*/*.js',

      'app.module.js',
      'app.config.js',
      'app.constants.js',
      'controllers/*.js',

    ], 'public/js/main.js');
});
```

Thanks for answers! Have a nice day :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript error Unknown provider: tProvider <- t after Rails minification Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950181/javascript-error-unknown-provider-tprovider-t-after-rails-minification-angul)

Comment: Thanks, I've forgot to configure angular .run as min safe :)